# Error in VScode Debugger since I updated nodejs version from 6.10 to 8.10

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, vscode-debugger

Since I upgraded my node-lambda project from 6.10 node version to 8.10 my debug failed.

My config  is:

```
{
    // informations: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    // usefull environnement variables list at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Node Lambda ",
            "program": "/usr/local/bin/node-lambda",
            "args": [
                "run"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "debug",
            "postDebugTask": "clean",
            "runtimeVersion": "8.10.0",
            // "protocol": "inspector"
        },
}
```

this is my output error message:

```
/home/gwendal/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/node --inspect-brk=24258 ../../../../usr/local/bin/node-lambda run 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:24258/d27c6111-ae5e-482a-a27a-e88829fd409f
Debugger attached.
Runtime [nodejs8.10] is not supported.
main.js:53
```

I don't find a way to make it works...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I didn't update my node-lambda as sudo and with -g so the 11.7 version (needed for node 8.10) didn't work. All is right now.